# matlab - applying a movement vector filed matrix on an original state matrix

Tags: matlab

I'm pretty new to matlab. I have 2 matrices representing an original state (MatA) and the state at time (t+1) (MatB). I've managed to calculate the movement vector field between the 2 matrices (VectMat).

Now, what i would like to do is to give a prediction for time t+2 - based on my vector field. i.e. - somehow apply the vector field marix (vectMat) on MatB and get a new matrix (Matc). I need to compare MatC to an actual result to see if the vector movement matrix makes a good movement prediction...

How would you do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you give a code sample showing what you are doing right now, and what you have tried to solve your problem?

Comment: It depends entirely on the type of problem you are tackling: of course if it is a linear evolution you are modeling then you will just have to "apply" VecMat to MatB in order to obtain MatC, but if you are dealing for instance with wave propagation then you will need to numerically solve your evolution equation (there are various way to do that). What evolution are you trying to predict ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you could think of is

```
vectMat = MatB - MatA;
MatC = MatB + vectMat;
```

where you assume that each time step causes a linear change in matrix elements, and you add the difference between `MatA` (time t) and `MatB` (time t+1) to `MatB` to get the matrix `MatC` for time t+2.

If you need something more complex, you need to tell us more about your problem ;-).